# Failing to display user location SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Before i post my code, i should tell you that my code run on a project and on a second project doesn't run!

The error that I get is:

```
[MKCoreLocationProvider] CLLocationManager(<CLLocationManager: 0x280cfc050>) for <MKCoreLocationProvider: 0x283cd0870> did fail with error: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
```

This is really wired why my code run on a project and the project that I'm working on it right now doesn't! and I'm using the same version ios 14.

1. MapView

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
    
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
        
 typealias UIViewType = UIView
        
        
  func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
            Coordinator(self)
  }
             
  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
            let map = MKMapView()
            
            map.delegate = context.coordinator
            map.showsUserLocation = true
            return map
  }
        
  func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
            
  }
              
}
```

2. Coordinator

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        
 var control: MapView
        
 init(_ control: MapView) {
            self.control = control
 }
        
        
}
```

3. Location manager

```
class GetUserLocation: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
        
 let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
 @Published var location: CLLocation? = nil
        
 override init() {
  super.init()
            
  self.locationManager.delegate = self
  self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
  self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
  self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
  self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            
 }
        
        
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
           
            guard let location = locations.last else {
                return
            }
            
            self.location = location
  }
        
        
}
```

Comment: Have you enabled the same capabilities for both projects in Xcode?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes everything is the same exactly, and plist is updated also

Comment: What i have discovered is that init in LocationManager file number 3 it's not getting called i don't know why!!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having some rest, I started debugging the problem I found out that the `init()` function it's not getting called in file `3. Location manager`.

I tried to initialize the object from other files and guess what it did work without any problem, another wired thing here!

So the `init()` function is getting called from other files however in `4. UserLocationMapView` it doesn't get called and i couldn't understand why!

After having a cup of coffe I found out that in `SceneDelegate` I was calling the wrong view file, I had `UserLocationMapView` that display the map, however I was calling `3. MapView` in `SceneDelegate`.

That's a silly mistake, when you call both files in `SceneDelegate`, they display the map without a problem. So when you see the map being displayed in the simulator you will think that it's working, however one of them call the `init()` function and one of them doesn't have it.